# C++ STL set_union gets error vector iterator + offset out of range

Tags: c++, vector, stl, set-union

I am attempting to merge several vectors to create a resulting vector that is the union of the elements in the input vectors, using STL in C++. Each input is already in sorted order, and the elements are unsigned short.

I am getting an error "Expression: vector iterator + offset out of range", and I cannot tell why. This is a debug build, running in the Visual Studio 2013 debugger.

Here is the code:

```
std::vector <unsigned short> wl, temp;
int iS; std::vector <unsigned short>::iterator oi, it;
for (iS=0; iS<nScans; iS++)
{
    std::vector<unsigned short> sc(scan[iS].wavelength, scan[iS].wavelength + scan[iS].nWavelengths);
    oi=set_union(wl.begin(), wl.end(), sc.begin(), sc.end(), temp.begin());
    wl.assign(temp.begin(), oi); // temp is needed because destination cannot overlap source
}
```

The intent is that a vector of wavelengths from each scan (sc) will be merged into the vector wl. (The vector wl is then copied into a C++ array of unsigned short by code not shown here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`temp` has size zero, so `set_union` writes past its end. Change that to

```
set_union(wl.begin(), wl.end(), sc.begin(), sc.end(), std::back_inserter(temp));
wl = temp;
temp.clear();
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f307a5e871f8876)

Update: *Why the vector temp doesn't increase in size automatically?*
Imagine `temp` is empty and the following code is executed:

```
std::vector<unsigned short>::iterator it = temp.begin();
*it = 123; // Undefined behavior
++it;      // UB
*it = 456; // UB
```

That's exactly what `std::set_union` is doing. It just writes to the output iterator you provide and increments it. But the usual vector iterator doesn't add items, you have to add items with `push_back`. That's what `back_inserter` is doing, and that's why it is needed here.

Comment: I think I understand your suggestion, but can you explain why the vector temp doesn't increase in size automatically? I thought that was the purpose of the vector container: to expand as needed.

Comment: @Woody20 I've tried to explain, see my updated answer.